# How to test endpoint conectivity on WCF Client?

Tags: 2013, wcf

I have a list that I get from a BDC external source

```
System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding();
System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress endpoint = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://shp2013.mydomain.com:1377/BiztalkWCF/WcfService_ProjectA_BiztalkWCF.svc?wsdl");

WcfService_UCPIntranet_BiztalkWCFClient client = new WcfService_ProjectA_BiztalkWCFClient(binding, endpoint);
```

How do I test if the end point is accessible? I catch the timeout exception and I would like to return a "cached" SharePoint list in this case.

1. How do I test if the client can connect?
2. How do I return a SP List?

I have 2 days experience in SharePoint and inherited all these issues... Thanks in advance, any help or pointer is highly appreciated, I have 15+ tabs open goggling all this stuff.

Comment: Ok What i did was create a List that serves as cache, and when a timeout exception occurs I use that cached list. Don't know if it's the most elegant solution but it solves the problem.